# Excel com macro lento

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Boa tarde

Após um simples macro de copy paste, para actualizar uma folha de planeamento, o ficheiro de excel vai ficando progressivamente mais lento, tanto na execução da macro como na trabalhibilidade normal (escrever, arrastar conteudo etc).
A macro trabalha com muitas células mas quando a fiz não demorava tanto tempo.

Já tentei eliminar o screenupdating e continua.
Algumas sugestões?

```
Sheets("F 002 PLAN-NAVE1").Select
Range("B5:WH372").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Cálculos").Select
Range("C8").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("F 002 PLAN-NAVE2").Select
Range("B5:PY372").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Cálculos").Select
Range("WJ8").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Parcial").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Obrigado desde já

Comment: Tenta fazer menos `SELECT`, isso costuma consumir muito processamento, outra coisa, quando acabar a ação em uma "sheets", finalize ela, pode reduzir o consumo também.

Answer (score 1):

José boa tarde, segue o seguinte código, repeitando o comentário do Bruno Fonseca, não usar Select. Espero que ajude, é um código simples que faz referencia direto a sua fonte de dados, independente da planilha ativa. Execute **Sub Copia_E_Cola()**

```
Sub Copia_E_Cola()
    copiaECola planDeOrigen:="F 002 PLAN-NAVE1", intervalorDeOrigen:="B5:WH372", _
        planDeDestino:="Cálculos", celulaDeDestino:="C8"

    copiaECola planDeOrigen:="F 002 PLAN-NAVE2", intervalorDeOrigen:="B5:PY372", _
        planDeDestino:="Cálculos", celulaDeDestino:="WJ8"
End Sub


Private Function copiaECola(planDeOrigen As String, intervalorDeOrigen As String, planDeDestino As String, celulaDeDestino As String)
    Worksheets(planDeOrigen).Range(intervalorDeOrigen).Copy Destination:=Sheets(planDeDestino).Range(celulaDeDestino)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Se sua planilha tiver muitos cálculos adicione no início do código:

Application.Calculation  = xlCalculationManual

E no final:

Application.Calculation  = xlCalculationAutomatic